# scope of element explanation? Can't access element after change(function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having difficulties understanding the scope of selector id and it's life.

Been driving me nuts since I am not really a javascript programmer.

Here is my situation ...

I have a drop list created on a page with an id of "droplist"

I have an input field element with an id of "filearea" and an attribute of data-howmany="10"

When yo select a value from the drop list, I call  ...

```
$("#droplist").change(function() {
   bla
   bla
   do some ajax to retrieve from the db based on value from droplist
});
```

If I try to access the input attribute

```
var xxx = $("#filearea").data("howmany");
```

Like this ...

```
$("#droplist").change(function() {
   var xxx = $("#filearea").data("howmany");
   alert(xxx);
   bla
   bla
   do some ajax to retrieve from the db based on value from droplist
});
```

I get an undefined messsage.

If I move the file area outside of the change like this ...

```
var xxx = $("#filearea").data("howmany");
alert(xxx);

$("#droplist").change(function() {
   bla
   bla
   do some ajax to retrieve from the db based on value from droplist
});
```

It works.

Currently the Ajax call does nothing . In fact, if I comment out the ajax stuff, I still get Undefined.

Comment: Is the `$("#filearea")` element overritten or removed by the `blah blah` instructions? or on Ajax success? -- No one can answer with so few code.

Comment: Currently the Ajax call does nothing . In fact, if I comment out the ajax stuff, I still get Undefined.

Comment: All that is possible to say is that something happened to the element `$("#filearea")` between page load and when the change event fires. Check if the element still exist and if it still has the data attribute. If you instantiate a plugin on it, for example, the element may have been removed. Can't tell more with what you provide here.

Comment: After looking at it in the browser with inspector, the id has changed from "filearea" to some random string of characters.

Comment: Try to store the object only on page load: `var xxx = $("#filearea")` Then in the change handler: `console.log(xxx.data("howmany"));` OR use a parent selector that does not mutate to reach it.